# Plain-text file encryption and decryption

Tags: java, object-oriented, file, file-system, caesar-cipher

I have created an Encryption and Decryption Algorithm that encrypts plain text using a given cipher and also decrypts it back to the original notation. It works great.

This was my code for a coding test and the reviewer told me that the class structure is inverse of what is the right way of doing it and that it is sloppy at some places.

I want to know what is wrong with my structuring of classes, if anything. Does it look sloppy? Can someone please help me identify places where it is lacking Best Practices for Java?

I have a `MyBuilder` class which creates an instance of `MyAlgorithm`. 
`MyAlgorithm` has the methods to encrypt and decrypt text, and it extends another class called `EncryptionAndDecryption` where the actual logic of the algorithm resides.

---

```java
public class MyAlgorithm extends EncryptionAndDecryption {

    public enum Action {
        ENCRYPT,
        DECRYPT
    }

    protected MyAlgorithm(final String cipherCharSet) {
        super(cipherCharSet);
    }

    public String encryptText(final String cipher, final String plainText) {
        return encryptOrDecryptText(cipher, plainText, Action.ENCRYPT);
    }

    public String decryptText(String cipher, String encryptedText) {
        return encryptOrDecryptText(cipher, encryptedText, Action.DECRYPT);
    }

    public boolean encryptDirectory(String cipher, String baseDirectory) {
        // for each files and sub files in each sub directories, call the following method;
    // encryptOrDecryptFile(cipher, file, baseDirectory, Action.ENCRYPT));
    }

    public boolean decryptDirectory(String cipher, String baseDirectory) {
        // for each files and sub files in each sub directories, call the following method;
    // encryptOrDecryptFile(cipher, file, baseDirectory, Action.DECRYPT));
    }
}
```

```
public class EncryptionAndDecryption {

    private final String CIPHER_CHAR_SET;

    protected EncryptionAndDecryption(final String cipherCharSet) {
        this.CIPHER_CHAR_SET = cipherCharSet;
    }

    protected final String encryptOrDecryptText(final String cipher, final String inputText, final MyAlgorithm.Action action) {
         // method logic here
    }

    protected final void encryptOrDecryptFile(final String cipher, final Path filePath, final String baseDirectory, final MyAlgorithm.Action action) {
        // method logic here
    }
}
```

```
public class MyBuilder {

    private String CIPHER_CHAR_SET;

    private MyBuilder() {}

    public static MyBuilder builder() {
        return new MyBuilder();
    }

    public MyBuilder withCipherSet(String cipherSet) {
        this.CIPHER_CHAR_SET = cipherSet;
        return this;
    }

    public MyAlgorithm build() {
        return new MyAlgorithm(CIPHER_CHAR_SET);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyEncryptionApp {

    public static final String CIPHER_CHAR_SET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Exact 3 parameters required - [action] [key] [target]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String action, key, target;
        action = args[0];
        key = args[1];
        target = args[2];

        MyAlgorithm myAlgorithm = MyBuilder.builder()
                .withCipherSet(CIPHER_CHAR_SET)
                .build();

        if ("encrypt".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
            System.out.println(myAlgorithm.encryptText(key, target));

        } else if ("decrypt".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
            System.out.println(myAlgorithm.decryptText(key, target));

        } else if ("encryptDir".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

            if(myAlgorithm.encryptDirectory(key, target)) {
                System.out.println("Directory encryption Successful");
            }

        } else if ("decryptDir".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

            if(myAlgorithm.decryptDirectory(key, target)) {
                System.out.println("Directory decryption Successful");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("action [" + action + "] not implemented");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Code Review! I try to give a possible explanation of what the reviewer meant when he was talking about inverse class structure; in the `main` method this code is present:

```
MyAlgorithm myAlgorithm = MyBuilder.builder()
               .withCipherSet(CIPHER_CHAR_SET)
               .build();
```

But from your code `MyAlgorithm` is a subclass of `EncryptionAndDecryption` and this is the class where you defined the operations of encryption and decryption , so the method shoud have return an instance of class `EncryptionAndDecryption` instead of one subclass. 
Other problem: in the class `EncryptionAndDecryption` we have the below methods:

```
protected final String encryptOrDecryptText(final String cipher, final String inputText, final MyAlgorithm.Action action)

protected final void encryptOrDecryptFile(final String cipher, final Path filePath, final String baseDirectory, final MyAlgorithm.Action action)
```

With parameter `MyAlgorithm.Action action` the class `EncryptionAndDecryption` will be dependant from its subclass `MyAlgorithm` and without its subclass it cannot be even compiled.
In the class `EncryptionAndDecryption` I would make two distinct methods for encryption and decryption of strings, putting these related to files and directory in the subclass `MyAlgorithm`, deleting the enum value you are using to distinguish between the two operations.
Style problem : in the `main` method is present a list of `if` like this below:

```
if ("encrypt".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {}
```

Normally it is the string compared to the string literal like:

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt")) {}
```

You can substitute the list of `if` with a `switch` like documented in [strings-switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html).

Comment: `MyAlgorithm myAlgorithm = MyBuilder.builder()
               .withCipherSet(CIPHER_CHAR_SET)
               .build();`

The reason it returns `MyAlgorithm` is because I have thought of it as a public facing class which has 4 separate methods to encrypt and String and Files. It doesn't know anything about the implementation. The super class `EncryptionAndDecryption` contains 2 methods that has actual logic needed for the 4 methods in sub class. These are marked protected and final so no one outside of the package can access them, nor can a child override them.

Is this unconventional?

Comment: I agree that the use of Enum in super class creates a dependency on the child class, instead I should have made a separate enum file.

Comment: `if ("encrypt".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {}`

Agreed, that normally people do it other way round, but I recently learned that doing this way helps prevent NullPointerException.
And, ofcourse switch would have been much better choice here.

Comment: @winzhack999 I understand your point, maybe an alternative could be nesting class `EncryptionAndDecryption` inside  class `MyAlgorithm` like in [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) and so your `builder` returns just  a `MyAlgorithm` instance. This is one possible choice and  the reviewer probably had in his mind his personal solution to solve the problem.